# Xcode 5: How do I segue from a table view if the table view is edit-mode?

Tags: ios, xcode, tableview, segue, editmode

I have a simple table view that can segue to an update-view-contoller to edit that row when the user taps on a row.  Issue: I would like to segue to the update-view-contoller when the table view is in "edit-mode", otherwise nothing should happen.

I am using Storyboard to create the segue linking the prototype cell to the update-view-controller.

Any idea on how to make the segue work only if the table view is in "edit-mode"?

Here is my prepare for segue code that is invoked when the user taps on a row from the table view contoller.  My segue has an identerfied called "ShowUpdate":

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ShowUpdate"]) {

        UpdateViewController *updateviewcontroller = [segue destinationViewController];

        NSIndexPath *myIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

        int row = [myIndexPath row];

        NSString *selectedRow = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", row];

        updateviewcontroller.DetailModal = @[_Title[row], _Description[row], selectedRow];

    }

}
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about a simple if check for `isEditing` property of the tableView?

```
@property(nonatomic, getter=isEditing) BOOL editing
```

Instead of making a segue from a prototype cell, I would drag it from the ViewController itself, and then check the above property in the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` delegate method and perform the segue in code from there.

Plus, you would need to set allowSelectionDuringEditing property somewhere in viewDidLoad or so.

```
self.tableView.allowsSelectionDuringEditing = YES;
```

Code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (self.tableView.isEditing) {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ShowUpdate" sender:cell];
    }
}
```

Segue construction:

[image]

Comment: Hi, this suggestion works except that now the Done button does not work to exit EDIT-MODE? This line @property(nonatomic, getter=isEditing) BOOL editing; and this line  self.tableView.allowsSelectionDuringEditing = YES;   seem to make the DONE button not work.  Do you happen to know if there is specific code needed to make the DONE but work to exit EDIT-MODE?   Thank you very much :)

Comment: This line: @property(nonatomic, getter=isEditing) BOOL editing, is a copy from Apple's documentation. I used that to show the property of the tableView and that it has a different name for the getter. Just skip this line, don't include it in your code and the button will work. Sorry for the confusion.